# Doubt about how to edit a Preference Attribute using the FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

i started to use the Marketing Cloud recently but i'm facing some problems to update a Preference Attribute using the FuelSDK (ruby). So, basically i can just update the profile attribute seding the content through the API (sending the desired field on the Attributes tag during the SOAP request), but i can't do the same strategy to update a Preference Attribute.

Currently, i'm interesting to set some values (Profile and Preferences attributes) when i create a subscriber triggering a first email for the user (when the user create a new account) through the Triggered Email action.

I don't really know how i can update a Preference Attribute using the FuelSdk.

If someone could give some tips, i would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try to create a subscriber(http://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/subscribers/subscriber-create.html) while including preference attributes?

Comment: @DrewSimmons nothing happens. I have a Preference Attribute called HasAccount that i'm interesting to update when i create a subscriber. You can see the field in that image https://www.dropbox.com/s/4oal6erdjy90jwp/Screenshot%202015-02-17%2017.03.14.png?dl=0

Comment: Have you tried treating preference attributes as other properties?  Something like this?:   require 'fuelsdk'
myClient = FuelSDK::Client.new {'client' => { 'id' => CLIENTID, 'secret' => SECRET }}
subscriber = FuelSDK::Subscriber.new
subscriber.authStub = myclient
subscriber.props = {.., ..., ..., "Has Account" => true}
results = subscriber.post
p results

Answer (score 0):

Preference Attribute updates work fine for me:

```
def set_preference(emaiL_address, preference_name, new_value)
  new_subscriber = FuelSDK::Subscriber.new
  new_subscriber.authStub = @auth
  new_subscriber.props = {
    "EmailAddress" => emaiL_address,
    "Attributes" => [ { 'Name' => preference_name, 'Value' => new_value } ]
  }
  results = new_subscriber.patch
  puts "Setting: #{emaiL_address} set property #{preference_name} => #{new_value}, code=#{results.code}"
end
```